# VBA + Regex : test for numbers

Tags: regex, vba

Here is a regular expression that matches all numbers (like 23.4; 24; .123)

```
Const decimalPattern As String = "-?([0-9]+[\,\.][0-9]*)|([0-9]*[\,\.][0-9]+)|([0-9]+)"
```

Here is the code I use for testing numbers (I replace comma with dots )

```
regex.Pattern = decimalPattern
   If (regex.test(dmsExpression) = True) Then
       coord = Val(Replace(dmsExpression, ",", "."))
       convertDMSToDecimal = coord
       Exit Function
```

This test is giving me 'True' for all the expected numbers values. But I also want to test expressions for values like : "23 34 56", or "23-34-56"

The test returns 'True' in those cases, and I'd like it to return false. I just don't know what expression I should use, or how I can change my code to return 'False' for such cases.

Comment: What do you want to allow and what do you want to disallow?

Comment: Why not just use `decimal.TryParse`? Like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fluscD

Comment: You need to escape that period in `[\,.]`

Comment: @CaffGeek - OP is using VBA, which is not at .NET language

Comment: @TimWilliams, thanks, didn't see that. Funny what is and is not in VBA.

Comment: Do you want your test to apply to the WHOLE string? As it is, things like "24 abc" and "24 12.34 24" will return true.  If you want to change it so that only if the ENTIRE STRING matches the pattern does the test return true, you can add the begin anchor, "^" and the end anchor "$" to your pattern like so: "^-?([0-9]+[\,.][0-9])|([0-9][\,.][0-9]+)|([0-9]+)$".  If this solves your issue, please let me know and I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
(?!\d*[ -]\d)[^\d][+-]?\d*([.,]\d*)?(?<!-)(?!\d*[ -]\d)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uX2hQ4/1)